# lookup from multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (~8k rows) that contains a a few columns that correspond to a fixed values to be looked up.

Dataframe looks like this-(ish):

| class_name | size | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | L | green |
| First | L | blue |
| Second | XL | red |

Lookup table looks like this (a df or a nested python dict):

| class_name | size | blue | red | green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | L | 90 | 95 | 90 |
| First | XL | 100 | 105 | 100 |
| Second | XL | 100 | 105 | 100 |

What I'm looking for is an efficient way to add a new column *value* to my first df. Something like this:

| class_name | size | colour | *value* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | L | green | *90* |
| First | L | blue | *90* |
| Second | XL | red | *105* |

Right now I'm solving this with

```py
df['value'] = df.apply(
            lambda row: lookup_function(df['class_name'], df['size'], df['colour'])

# and that lookup_function includes the dict (or a df if that helps)
def lookup_function(class_name, size, colour):
    looky_here = {.. lookup table as dict structure ..}
    try:
        return float(looky_here[class_name][size][colour])
    except:
        return 0
```

This is quite slow (after my 8k df is processed, I have plenty of new 8k df's to do). How can I do this faster and more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider melting ([melt documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)) your lookup table:

```py
melted = lookup.melt(id_vars=['class_name', 'size'], value_vars=['blue', 'red', 'green'], var_name='colour')
```

Will generate :
[image]

At this point you can simply merge your first dataframe with it.

```py
df.merge(melted, on=['class_name', 'size', 'colour'])
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick and precise answer, I would probably never have found `.melt()` without this tip.